# How do I use jQuery in my html after npm install?

Tags: jquery, npm

After running `npm install jquery`, what then? I have tried:

```
import $ from "jquery.js";
var $ = require("jquery.js");
```

This code is in my `app.js` file which is connected to my html. jQuery code I write has no affect on the DOM.

Comment: why not use static folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use it like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

$(function () {
  // ...
});
```

If you use express add this as static route

```
app.use('/lib/jquery', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery/dist')));
```

And load it in your html file:

```
<script src="/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Maybe you have to modify the pathes.

Comment: You don't need to move the jQuery.min.js file. The static route loads it from the node_modules.